# How do I fix SelectedItem null in listBox when using Task issue

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, listbox, selecteditem

I have a problem with something setting up selectedItem in a listbox to null. But it does it every other time, and I can’ figure out why it happens. It only happens when I’m trying to use Task to get some data async. I created a very simple project to show the exact problem, which I find difficult to understand. 
So here is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="AsyncProblem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}" />
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Reload" Width="50" Height="50" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Here is my viewmodel:

```
namespace AsyncProblem
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Names = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Name", "Second Name",  "Third Name"};
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> names;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get { return names; }
        set
        {
            names = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string selectedName;
    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return selectedName; }
        set
        {
            selectedName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    Task loadTask;
    int counter = 0;
    public void LoadNewList()
    {
        counter++;
        loadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Names = new ObservableCollection<string>()
                {
                    string.Format("{0} new name", counter), 
                    string.Format("{0} second new name", counter),
                    string.Format("{0} third new name", counter)
                };
            });
    }
    public void ReselectSelectedName()
    {
        loadTask.ContinueWith(previousTask => SelectedName = Names.LastOrDefault());
    }
    }
}
```

And here is the calling code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainWindowViewModel dataContext;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = dataContext;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataContext.LoadNewList();
        dataContext.ReselectSelectedName();
    }
}
```

Now when I run this program and press the button, if gets the new list, but it does not set the selectedName. In fact what happens, the selected name changes to iza, and then somehow the selectedname set is called second time with a value of null. So of coursethe listbox loses its selected item.
Even worse is that, it only happens every second button click, when I try to hit the button again then I get the desired behaviour and again the behaviour gets wrong and so on.

Can anybody explain what happens behind the scene?

Thank you

Comment: You should never ever unset/replace your `ObservableCollection`. When you do that, WPF needs to rebind everything. Make your `ObservableCollection` readonly. Then only use `Add` and `Remove` on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I doubt this is causing the problem, because if I leave it as it is and just remove everything to do with the task, then it works. But the collection will be coming from a database, so I don’t want to block the app while waiting for it.

Comment: You are wrong. WPF is able to marshal the call back to the UI thread. I've been working with WPF for years now. I am very very very sure that it IS indeed the line `Names = new ObservableCollection<string>()`. You should take a look at the source code to the `CollectionView` class that is involved in the binding of a collection to a view object.

Comment: If you don't believe me, just try calling `OnPropertyChanged("Names")` at any point on any thread, and watch as the ListBox loses its selected item. BTW OnPropertyChanged is actually called with a string parameter, but the .net 4.5 compiler adds that automagically.

Comment: I know it is, I just added CallerMemberName, so I don't have to pass that string. I tried to clear the collection and add to it, as suggested in answer below, but now I have an exception. So I'm researching this exception to see, because I still think its related to that task, as I did not have that problem before I introduced the task. I will look at your suggestion and @Khan as soon as I fix this.

Comment: That exception is the famous "This CollectionView does not support threads Exception" (or something to that effect), problem is, no one has ever bothered to make one that does support threads. You MUST call each method on ObservableCollection from the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, you are right the problem was the thread, I had to split the task into two tasks, the first one would simulate the delay, and the second one needed this, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); It works regardless of Names.Clear() and then Add, or just new observable collection. But I will spend some time tomorrow to read about what you said. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `LoadNewList` method, you're creating a new collection for `Names`:

```
Names = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "New Daniel", "New James", "New Colin", "New Bruno", "Iza" };
```

Doing this is breaking your existing binding.

Trying adding/removing/emptying the collection instead:

```
Names.Clear();
Names.Add("New Daniel");
...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time, this would not fix my issue, but instead I had to create a second task which simulates the delay, and the task which I have in the code above needed this TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());